# What is the fastest way to read the SQL Data (Millions of records) from database SQLite C# Service Stack

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlite, ormlite-servicestack

I am working on Ormlite-ServiceStack  with SQLite as a database. **I am retrieving the millions (1195935)** of records from SQLite database table in single Select query (C# DotNet and Database is SQLite (v4.0.30319)) as below.

Store procedure is not supported in SQLite.

The whole process is taking more than 30 sec for retrieving the data by single query. How can I improve the performance at Millisecond  level.  I have tried by other ways like Entity Framework, SQLiteData Adapter but not able to up the speed for fetch the data from database at millisecond level.

My Machine is also very fast Solid State Drive with 16 GB RAM, X64 based Windows 7 professional.

---

```
public string connectionstring** = "Data Source =  " + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabasePath"].ToString() + ";";

public class ClientSideDataResponse
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ByDevSessionId { get; set; }
    public int ByDeviceId { get; set; }
    public int value1 { get; set; }
    public int value2 { get; set; }
    public int  SequenceId{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

    public List< ClientSideDataResponse> executeReadQuery_List_ClientSideData() 
    {
        System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand myCommand = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand();
        List<ClientSideDataResponse> results = new List<ClientSideDataResponse>();

        String _query = "SELECT ID, ByDevSessionId, ByDeviceId, Value1, Value2,  SequenceId, Timestamp   FROM ClientSideData ORDER BY ID";

        try
        {
            using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection con = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed || con.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }

                    using (var transaction = con.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = _query;
                        try
                        {
                            System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                 ClientSideDataResponse  newItem = new ClientSideDataResponse();

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["ID"].ToString()) == true)
                                {
                                    newItem.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["ByDevSessionId"].ToString()) == true)
                                {
                                    newItem.ByDevSessionId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ByDevSessionId"]);
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["ByDeviceId"].ToString()) == true)
                                {
                                    newItem.ByDeviceId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ByDeviceId"]);
                                }  
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["Value1"].ToString()) == true)
                                {
                                    newItem.Value1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Value1"]);
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["Value2"].ToString()) == true)
                                {
                                    newItem.Pulse = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Value2"]);
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["SequenceId"].ToString()) == true)
                                {
                                    newItem.SequenceId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["SequenceId"]);
                                }
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["Timestamp"].ToString()) == true)
                                {
                                    newItem.Timestamp = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Timestamp"].ToString());
                                }

                                results.Add(newItem);
                            }
                            reader.Close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        { 
                            logger.Debug(ex.Message);
                            return results;
                        }

                        transaction.Commit();
                        cmd.Dispose();

                        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            con.Close();
                        }
                        return results;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             logger.Debug(ex.Message);
            return results;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you using the result for? Do you really need to retrieve all the data?

Comment: 40K records per seconds does not sound too bad... What is your performance goal?

Comment: What do you mean by "improve the performance at Millisecond level"? Are you expecting this number of data to be read in a few milliseconds?

Comment: 1.2 million records in 30 seconds from a flat-file relational database is not bad at all, especially with the Order By. If you need something faster, scale up your database to something like SqlServer or MySql.

Comment: Try removing `transaction` and `order by`, use profiler to understand where your program spends most time.

Comment: Hi,I have created the web service and its always connected with 100 of clients (Android Application On Samsung Tablets for Display the LINE Graph and Refresh in every 5 seconds). 

At the same time the Database writing operation is going on of atleast 1000 Records Per minute by 10 client (80 millisecond will take to insert the data by each client /1000 record).

 If the Read data is  millions the system would become hang because of Data base locked.

Comment: Based on the previous comment, you are using the wrong database backend for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am using Web service ServiceStack.OrmLite.4.0.32 with SQlite (v4.0.30319). My web service is access by 100 of Android application and all can be able to Update and retrive at any time. I have to Dsiplay the Line Graph that with refresh evry 5 to 15 seconds (editable). My Database would locked frequently if million of data

I can not post my original code. I have just change the class name for the query on Stackoverflow.

Comment: But do you really need all millions of rows of data to plot the line graph?

Comment: You aren't using ServiceStack in your code.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few thing you can do to speed things up. (But it will probably not make it a lot faster)

1. Create an index if needed to increase performance for the `order by`. Look at the execution plan for the query. Or even better, remove the `order by` if not needed by the consumer.
2. Set the capacity of the result list to something that would be close to the result if it is known. `new List<ClientSideDataResponse>(1200000);`
3. Instead of converting to and from `string` use the real value from the database. (Unless of course the values in the database is actually strings. Then it needs to be redesigned)

This:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["ID"].ToString()) == true)
{
     newItem.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
}
```

Would instead be:

```
if(!reader.IsDBNull(0)) //0 is the index of the column.
   newItem.ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
```

Same for all other results from the query.

Answer (score 2):

ServiceStack has selection methods which do all of this for you.

Chek [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) project. It handles SQLite databases too.

You will just have to call something like:

```
var results = Db.Select<ClientSideDataResponse>(); // That's all folks!
```

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that no one told you not to retrieve millions of records from a single query. Especially since its tagged `asp.net` (web). Just pull a total count and the records you need for the current page. Now determine your page size and create your custom pagination and when user clicks on page 'n' retrieve that nth page. For page n the algorithm will be

```
 records.Skip( (n-1) * page_size ).Take( page_size )
```

if you are using EntityFramework.

Comment: That was the first comment on the question.